# in python , how to split string with certain condition?

Tags: python

How can i tell python to search for certain character or certain letter in a string for example search for 'a' then look what follows it . if a 'b' follows 'a' then put '.' before the 'b' thus the result will be '.ba' while if any thing othere than 'b' follows 'a' then join them with 'a'

Comment: Do you also want to reverse the order of the `'a'` and `'b'`, or was that a typo? If all you want is to replace `'ab'` with `'.ba'` just use `yourString.replace('ab','.ba')`.

Comment: learn [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: regexes are useful... but if the case is really this straightforward, using regex is a bit like killing a fly with a machine gun.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard `.replace()` method on a string will work fine. Your particular example is slightly confusing, but consider the following:

```
text = 'I know a girl who is so unhappy she cries all the time.'
print(text.replace('unhappy', 'un.happy'))
# Output: I know a girl is so un.happy she cries all the time.
```

Comment: sorry if i was ambigous because i am a bigenner in python , let me tell you other example in a word like 'unhappy' i want to tell python if you found un that perceads 'happy' put '.' after 'un'.so the result will be 'un.happy'

Comment: I replaced my example using unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want code that will let you search for arbitrary patterns in perhaps a flood of incoming arbitrary strings, and edit the strings using the simple rule that if a 'b' follows an 'a' then you want to put a dot between them, so if you get 'abba' as input, you'd get 'a.bba' as output. I also assume you only want to make this edit to the first instance of 'ab' in each string. If that's not the case, remove the '1' from my 'replace' call:

```
instrings = ['abba', 'belabor', 'sudo', 'balance', 'rabid', 'ababab']
for s in instrings:
    s = s.replace('ab', 'a.b', 1)
    print(s)
```

Hope this helps.